# Pandas: How to create a new column in a Dataframe and add values in it considering other existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-engineering

I have a data frame representing some restaurants and their names.

- **What i want to do is to add a column `is_chain` to my initial Dataframe `df` that represents if the restaurant is a food chain or not.** This new column Takes 0 or 1. The value 1 indicates that the restaurant is part of a chain (eg McDonald's).A restaurant is considered to be part of a chain, if there is another restaurant in the database with the same name.

```py
data = {
        'restaurant_id':  ['1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
        'restaurant_name':  ['Dennys', 'Dennys','Pho U','Pho U','Dennys','Japanese Cafe','Japanese Cafe','Midori','Midori','xxx','yyy','zzz'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['restaurant_id','restaurant_name'])

df.head(15)
```

So for example here, `xxx`, `yyy` and `zzz` are not part of a chain.

I'm not sure about the correct syntax using pandas to achieve something like this. If any clarifications needed, please ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `duplicated`:

```
 df['is_chain'] = df['restaurant_name'].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   restaurant_id restaurant_name  is_chain
0              1          Dennys         1
1              2          Dennys         1
2              3           Pho U         1
3              4           Pho U         1
4              5          Dennys         1
5              6   Japanese Cafe         1
6              7   Japanese Cafe         1
7              8          Midori         1
8              9          Midori         1
9             10             xxx         0
10            11             yyy         0
11            12             zzz         0
```

Comment: Thank you !, what does keep=False does here?. And also, does astype(int) converts boolean into Integer?

Comment: Defaul of `duplicated` is `keep='first'`, that is the first occurrence is not counted as duplicated. Setting `keep=False` also masks the first one as duplicated. Answer to the second question is Yes.